# Solution of diophantine equation with lowest c

Tags: diophantine-equations, linear-programming, diophantine-approximation, linear-diophantine-equations

Lets say I have a diophantine equation ,

**aX - bY = c**

Now, for some (a,b,c) I may not have any integer solution at all. 
But lets say , I write the equation in this way ,

**aX - bY = c + p**

p is an integer . (positive or negative)

So, I can increase the value of **c** by **(c+p)** if there are no solution for (a,b,c).
I need to find a triplet **(a,b,c+p)** for which solution exist and p is minimum(absolute value).

If , already I have solution for (a,b,c) then p is just 0.

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: My idea so far ,G =  gcd(a,b) = k*(c+p) , so , p = (G/k-c)

Comment: $$aX-bY=c$$ has an integer solution as soon as $\gcd(a,b)$ is a divisor of $c$, so you just have to look at the intersection of two arithmetic progressions.